# using and operator for Eclipse Java coding

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting my and operator working in eclipse. I have used it before but can't figure out why it is not working this time. It tells me that:
"The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int"
can someone please help me?

Here is the code:

```
public boolean setScore1(int score1) {
  if (score1 >= -1 && <= 100) {  // this line has error
    this.score1 = score1;
    return true;    
  }
  else      
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fully specify both the left and right sides of the binary operator such as `<=`; it will not implicitly pick up the `score1` from the other condition like we would in English.

Explicitly state the condition:

```
 if (score1 >= -1 && score1 <= 100)
```

Comment: thank you very much. I am still fairly new to java coding, still in college for it, and I always seem to forget something. This has solved the problem. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a second comparison reference to variable `score1`.

Try using the following condition instead:

```
if (score1 >= -1 && score1 <= 100) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (score1 >= -1 && score <= 100)`

Logically, it makes sense to say "if score is larger than -1 and less than 100" but the computer doesn't recognize that. For the computer, you have to say "if the score is large than -1 and **the score** is less that 100."